# Prove $\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} =(1- \sum_{n \ge 1} (n-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!}) ^{-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, formal-power-series, algebraic-combinatorics, lagrange-inversion

Is it possible to prove that

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} =(1- \sum_{n \ge 1} (n-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!}) ^{-1}$$

Where $(n-1)^{n-1} := 1$ for $n=1$

Idea:use the Lagrange inversion theorem

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n \ge1} {r(n) \frac{x^n}{n!}}= R(x) /x $$

Comment: No need to use Lagrange inversion. You can multiply the LHS by $(1- \sum_{n \ge 1} (n-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^n}{n!})$ and see if you get $1$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp but can it be done using Lagrange inversion as well?

Comment: Lagrange inversion is for functional inversion. Are you referring to that or to multiplicative inversion (just 1 divided by the series)?

Comment: @GiulioR I'm referring to "the lagrange inversion theorem" (inversion of formal power series)

Comment: Lagrange inversion finds the compositional inverse.
Namely given $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}f_nx^n$ with $f_1\not=0$ it provides $g(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}g_nx^n$ such that $f(g(x))=x=g(f(x))$ by the formula $g_n=\frac 1n \mathrm{res}_{x=0} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{f(x)^n}$. Note that both series $f,g$ have to start with linear terms.
In your case, both series start with constant terms (with 1).

Comment: Actually Lagrange inversion also gives all complex (multiplicative) powers of a compositional inverse. Now it seems you are dealing with the Lambert function; if your formula it is correct it must coincide with the one given here (for the power $r=-1$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Integer_and_complex_powers